# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined at Constructor.render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a contact form, and getting this error while accessing the values. I have debugged it a several times in the console menu, but it seems that I am missing some or the other thing, can somebody help?

```
    var fieldValues = {
     name     : null,
    email    : null,
    contact  : null,
    age      : null

     }

     var Contactform = React.createClass({

      save(){
          var data = {
           name     : this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value,
           contact  : this.refs.contact.getDOMNode().value,
           email    : this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value,
           age      : this.refs.age.getDOMNode().value,
         }

      },

    render: function(){

        return(
                <div>
                <label>Name</label> 
                <form>
                <input type="text"
                       ref="name"
                       defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.name } />

                        <label>contact</label>
                        <input type="contact"
                               ref="contact"
                               defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.contact } />

                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email"
                               ref="email"
                               defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.email } />

                        <label> age</label>
                        <input type="age"
                               ref="age"
                               defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.age}/>    

                               <button onClick={ this.save}>Save</button></form></div>
        )
    }

 })


     ReactDOM.render(<Contactform/>,
      document.getElementById('react-container'))
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Changes**:

**1.** You forgot to pass the `props` in component `Contactform` and you are accessing the value by:

```
this.props.fieldValues.name
```

Because of that it is throwing the error, Use this to pass `props`:

```
<Contactform fieldValues={fieldValues}/>
```

**2.** Instead of

`this.refs.name.getDOMNode().value`

Use this to access the value:

```
this.refs.name.value
```

Because `this.refs.name` refer to the `dom element`, and you can access the value of that by `this.refs.name.value`.

Check the working example:

```js
var fieldValues = {
     name     : null,
    email    : null,
    contact  : null,
    age      : null

     }

     var Contactform = React.createClass({

      save(e){
        e.preventDefault();
          var data = {
           name     : this.refs.name.value,
           contact  : this.refs.contact.value,
           email    : this.refs.email.value,
           age      : this.refs.age.value,
         }
         console.log(data)
      },

    render: function(){

        return(
                <div>
                <label>Name</label> 
                <form>
                <input type="text"
                       ref="name"
                       defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.name } />

                        <label>contact</label>
                        <input type="contact"
                               ref="contact"
                               defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.contact } />

                        <label>Email</label>
                        <input type="email"
                               ref="email"
                               defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.email } />

                        <label> age</label>
                        <input type="age"
                               ref="age"
                               defaultValue={ this.props.fieldValues.age}/>    

                               <button onClick={ this.save}>Save</button></form></div>
        )
    }

 })


     ReactDOM.render(<Contactform fieldValues={fieldValues}/>,
      document.getElementById('react-container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='react-container'/>
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass fieldValues variable react component as a property.